# How to correctly fix unclosed HTML tags with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have difficulty getting HTML generated by a site. The HTML contains some tags that are not closed.

For example:

```
<div>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>
        test
      </div>

  <li>
     <div>
       test 
     </div>
```

Parsing the HTML:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open('origin.html'))
```

Results in:

[image: Nokogiri object]

Or, in HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

    <html><body>
      <div>

        <li>
          <div>
            <div>
              test
            </div>

        <li>
          <div>
            test 
          </div>

    </li>
    </div>
    </li>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I believe that the right thing would be something like:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <body>
    <div>
      <li>
        <div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>
           test 
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to solve this? Change to another gem? Use regex to change the HTML before parsing?

Comment: Please, indent your code blocks properly, it's hard to see where each tag closes.

Comment: @AlexeyShein done! Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using images to demonstrate issues with data or code, copy and paste the text into the question, and format it correctly for readability. That helps us help you as we can reuse the data without having to type it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at using [Nokogumbo](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogumbo) which attaches [Googles’ Gumbo HTML5 parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) to Nokogiri. This will then use the HTML5 error correcting algorithms when parsing malformed HTML, rather than the default parsing performed my Nokogiri and libxml, and will result in parsed HTML closer to what you would expect to see from a browser.

Here’s an example `irb` session showing how it handles your example HTML and produces the result you are after. Note the method name is `HTML5`, and it is still called on the `Nokogiri` module.

```
>> require 'nokogumbo'
=> true
>> s = <<EOT
<div>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>
        test
      </div>

  <li>
     <div>
       test
     </div>
EOT
=> "<div>\n  <li>\n    <div>\n      <div>\n        test\n      </div>\n\n  <li>\n     <div>\n       test \n     </div>\n"
>> puts Nokogiri.HTML5(s).to_html
<html>
<head></head>
<body><div>
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>
        test
      </div>

  </div>
</li>
<li>
     <div>
       test
     </div>
</li>
</div></body>
</html>
=> nil
```

Comment: Awesome! Work fine!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You believe that your `<li>` should not be nested? Let's try to understand why `Nokogiri` parses it this way:

```
<div>
  <li>
    <div>  <!-- unclosed div -->
      <div>
        test
      </div>    
      <li>
        <div>
           test 
        </div>
```

First, your HTML is invalid because (besides missing closing tags) there's no `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag, so Nokogiri switches to guessing right away, from the first `<li>` tag.

Next, let's look at the specs about end-tag omitting: `<li>` [may omit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) its end tag, but `<div>` [may not omit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) it.

The way you nested `<li>`-tags, Nokogiri tries to find the closing tag of the second `<div>` (see the HTML comment in the code listing above) and chooses the lesser evil, although there's no nested `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix unterminated/unclosed tags depends on what your goal is. @Matt's suggestion is sound, however it can still result in bad HTML if the original HTML is pathologically wrong, and, at that point you have to step in and do fix-ups prior to letting any other parser attempt to make sense of it.

Whether that requires using regular expressions or simple string manipulation or extracting the specific line and parsing it as a fragment depends on the situation. I've had to do some pretty ugly things just to be able to use a parser on badly broken HTML multiple times, and each time it was a different process.